# how to include an xml file into my netbeans

Tags: java, xml, netbeans

I am abit new to java so,i would need a simplified answer..

Suppose i have an xml file given below

```
<xml>
<name>boy</name>
</xml>
```

now, i have read about the types of parser, DOM and SAX. my main problem is how to add this xml file into my working environment. I am currently using Netbeans and i don't know how to include it into my project. Anyone with idea or a full working xml project? I just need it to study how to work with xmls. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To address the specifics of doing this in netbeans (I'm using NB7.1 but it's probably pretty much the same in earlier versions), if you want to include the xml file in your netbeans project, simply create it in the source package by right-clicking the package and selecting 'New'. This will give you a list of file types. If the option for 'XML Document' is in the list then select it, otherwise select 'Other' from the list under 'New' and find it from there. From there, just fill in the details in the wizard screens.

This will create it in your project. Bear in mind this means it will be included in the compiled .jar file, so is only useful if the file is something like fixed configuration data or a test file. For learning and testing purposes, you could always just hard-code the path of the file, but to do it correctly you can use the 'getResource' function of the class loader, something like

```
URL myxmlfile = yourclassname.class.getResource("/packagename/xmlfilename.xml");
```

Obviously substitute your own class, package and file names in there. The path you pass to getResource is relative to the top of your project, and it returns a full name identifying where the file is, which will either be a 'file://' URL or a 'jar://' URL, depending on whether the class file gets run from within a .jar file or not. The class loader handles these details. You can then pass to the 'parse' method of the parser as was previously mentioned. You'll probably need to convert it from a URL object to a string first with 'myxmlfile.toString()'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [htmlcleaner](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/) to handle your xml file.

To handle your xml file take a look at [Clean method](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/doc/org/htmlcleaner/HtmlCleaner.html#clean%28java.io.File%29):

```
HtmlCleaner cleaner = new HtmlCleaner();
File file = new File('path of your xml file');
cleaner.clean(file);
//logic here
```

There is no need to include file in your netbeans. File-handling will be done by the xml parser library you are using.

Comment: i didn't downvote your comment. I would want more light on this. You mean when i just start writing the DOM parser code, file-handling will be done by the DOM parser without it knowing where the xml file is located on my machine?

Comment: `DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();`
`dom = db.parse("employees.xml");` here instead of `employees.xml` pass complete path of xml file. For eg: "C:\source\myxml\test.xml".